# Why does the environment tag helper work on my machine but not on Azure?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, aspnetboilerplate, tag-helpers

This is a section on our _Layout.cshtml that I'm about to throw out the window.

```razor
<!-- CSS Scripts -->
    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="/ts/CS.js" asp-append-version="true" abp-ignore-src-modification="true"></script>
        <script src="/ts/CS.Url.js" asp-append-version="true" abp-ignore-src-modification="true"></script>
        <script src="/ts/CS.Settings.js" asp-append-version="true" abp-ignore-src-modification="true"></script>
        <script src="/ts/CS.Alert.js" asp-append-version="true" abp-ignore-src-modification="true"></script>
        <script src="/ts/CS.Modal.js" asp-append-version="true" abp-ignore-src-modification="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment include="Staging,Production">
        <script abp-src="/ts/CS.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script abp-src="/ts/CS.Url.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script abp-src="/ts/CS.Settings.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script abp-src="/ts/CS.Alert.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script abp-src="/ts/CS.Modal.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
```

We use the environment tag helper in some spots to either use .min.js or .js, useful for debugging. I can see that if I personally set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable from "Development" to "Production" that the tag helper continues to render the right content.

However, when I then push this through to be hosted on Azure - the content is missing completely.

Things I've tried:

- Tried changing the value in azure config - no change.
- Originally we had `names`, changed to `include` - no change. Still works on dev machine.

What is going on here?! Is this not what other people do?

Comment: when you write "the value in azure config", do you mean you set the "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" in your webservice configuration?

Comment: Specifically in the AppService > Configuration > Application Settings. I didn't add it there, it was there by default and is correctly set to "Production". Here's what it looks like: [link](https://imgur.com/a/AXxO4AE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staging, production is not understandable to the server. You need to change this as follow.

If You are working in local than our script will work which is inside

```
<environment include="Development">
</environment>
```

if You are working on server like azure and others than our script will work which is inside

```
<environment exclude="Development">
</environment>
```

You need to change your following code

```
<environment include="Staging,Production">
        <script abp-src="/ts/CS.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script abp-src="/ts/CS.Url.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script abp-src="/ts/CS.Settings.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script abp-src="/ts/CS.Alert.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script abp-src="/ts/CS.Modal.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>    </environment>
```

as

```
<environment exclude="Development">
                <script abp-src="/ts/CS.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
                <script abp-src="/ts/CS.Url.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
                <script abp-src="/ts/CS.Settings.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
                <script abp-src="/ts/CS.Alert.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
                <script abp-src="/ts/CS.Modal.js" asp-append-version="true"></script> 
   </environment>
```

It will work at any server.

Comment: You're right. Looking at a template generated today, that's exactly what it looks like. I swear this used to be different ..

Answer (score 2):

The `exclude="Development"` works if you want to apply the same settings to all other environment except `Development`. But I came across a time when I need to have different settings for staging and production. So I had to be specific.

The solution I use in order for the environment tag helper to work on Azure is that you need to create an entry for the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` under **Settings -> Configuration -> Application settings** on Azure:

[image]

If you don't have that defined on Azure, when you publish, it will default to **Production** if I remember correctly, which is weird.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue with asp.net 3.0. It was rendering environment on local properly but when I deployed to Azure it stopped detecting it and rendering both the environment as it is.

Here is the solution. Just add the below line in your _Layout.cshtml file in the beginning.

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

[image]
it will fix the issue.

thanks